# Insert Array of Array perl

Tags: perl

I have an array of array

```
@data = [["Hi", "Hello"],["Apple", "Orange"]];
```

And I need to insert a new array

> @a = ["a", "b"];

I would like that the array @data looks like this

```
@data = [["Hi", "Hello"],["Apple", "Orange"], ["a", "b"]];
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

When you type

```
[ "foo", "bar", "base" ]
```

it's not a simple array, but a reference to an array:

```
my $ref = [ "foo", "bar", "base" ];
print $ref;
```

Displays by example:

```
ARRAY(0x1d79cb8)
```

A simple *array* is `@array` assigned to this simple *list*:

```
my @array = ( "foo", "bar", "base" )
```

Still using a reference:

```
use Data::Dumper;

# Using $array_ref to store the reference.
# There's no reason to use an @array to store a
# memory address string...
$array_ref = [["Hi", "Hello"],["Apple", "Orange"]];

# Pushing in the dereferenced array ref
push @$array_ref,  ["a", "b"];

# Let's the doctor take a look in this body
print Dumper $array_ref;
```

**Output**:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'Hi',
            'Hello'
          ],
          [
            'Apple',
            'Orange'
          ],
          [
            'a',
            'b'
          ]
        ];
```

Seems what you expect, no?

---

See [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Comment: Your second example is not an array, it's a [list](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl). There's no literal syntax for arrays in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
@data = [                #Open Square Bracket
   ["Hi", "Hello"],
   ["Apple", "Orange"]
];                       #Close Square Bracket
```

And not this:

```
@data = (                #Open Parentheses   
   ["Hi", "Hello"],
   ["Apple", "Orange"]
);                       #Close Parentheses
```

The `[...]` syntax is used to define a *reference* to an array while `(...)` is defined as an array.

In the first one, we have an array `@data` with one member `$data[0]`. This member contains a reference to an array which is composed of two more array references.

In the second one, we have an array `@data` with two members, `$data[0]` and `$data[1]`. Each of these members contain one reference to another array.

Be very, very careful about that! I'm going to assume you meant the second one.

Let's use some syntactic sugar that can clean things up a bit. This is what you're representation looks like:

```
my @data;
$data[0] = ["Hi", "Hello"];
$data[1] = ["Apple", "Orange"];
```

Each entry in your array is a *reference* to another array. Since `@data` is merely an array, I can use `push` to push elements to the end of the array:

```
push @data, ["a", "b"];
```

Here I'm pushing another array reference. I could have done this too if it makes it easier to understand:

```
my @temp = ("a", "b");
push @data, \@temp;
```

I've created an array called `@temp`, and then pushed a reference to `@temp` onto `@data`.

You can use [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) to display your structure. This is a standard Perl module, so it should already be available on your installation:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;

my @data = (
    [ "Hi", "Hello"],
    [ "Apple", "Orange"],
);

push @data, ["a", "b"];
say Dumper \@data;
```

This will print out:

```
$VAR1 = [             # @data
      [           # $data[0]
    'Hi',
    'Hello'
      ],
      [           # $data[1]
    'Apple',
    'Orange'
      ],
      [           # $data[2]
    'a',
    'b'
      ]
    ];
```